# Module is undefined for dynamic import of a named export from an external package

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, dynamic-import, react-icons

I want to import icons from `react-icons` as defined by an array of strings corresponding to named exports of icon components from `react-icons`.
I cover the cases for each library of icons from `react-icons`. This is an example of a case for FontAwesome.

`lazy(() => import('react-icons/fa').then(module => ({ default: module.Components[icon]})))`

The above code snippet was found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/64#discussion_r226683684) as a method of dynamically importing named exports.

I expect this to return a component corresponding to the icon specified by `icon`, for example `let icon = 'FaPhp';`
What's happening is an error which says: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'FaPhp' of undefined`

Comment: FWIW your error means that `module.Components` is undefined.  I suggest adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(module)))` to your `then` lambda to see what is actually in the module object.

Comment: It's probably supposed to be `module.exports` not `module.Components`

Comment: @sjagr I am using Components otherwise I just have a string which is the name of the desired named export.

Comment: @Brandon thank you I will try that. I may need to just import Components from 'react'.

Comment: @Brandon I got something unexpected. Console found ["loaded","id","exports","webpackPolyfill"]

Comment: Okay, so if I use `module.FaPhp`, the icons render. So now, I'm just figuring out how to use the strings I have of the component names, hence why I was using `Components[icon]`.

Comment: `module[icon]` is what you want then.

Comment: @Brandon close, I got it figured out last night (see answer) I had to use Icon instead of icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React expects all components to be named with a leading capital letter. Therefor, I renamed the iterator `icon` to `Icon`, then I omitted the `module.Components[icon]`and replaced it with `module[Icon]` which solved my issue!

I figured this out from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823090/how-to-render-a-react-component-from-a-string-name) and decided to use the array access notation after realizing I was accessing the library of elements through module.